# How can I have a particular timestamp from a SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, nvl

I have a table in which timestamp is stored as `varchar` in the format `20120419170525`. The column also has some null values.

In a `SELECT` query, I want to apply `NVL(my_timestamp, to_timestamp(SYSDATE))`, if the value is null then it should display the current timestamp in the same format.

I tried this statement before executing query sql statement:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'.
```

but didn't get the desired result. I am getting in this format `YYYY MM DD HH24:MI:SS`

What can be the solution or I need to write a procedure to support this format?

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Comment: You're using a deprecated character data-type to store a date as a number? What's wrong with just putting your date into a `date` data-type?

Comment: @Ben: I have not created the table...the table was being used since a long. I have given u just a scenario not the exact table-name. now I have to perform certain operations on it...so that why i was in problem, how to operate it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
select nvl(my_timestamp, to_char(systimestamp, 'yyyymmddhh24miss'))
from your_table
```

But since you don't really use the "timestamp part" you can stay with sysdate:

```
select nvl(my_timestamp, to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmddhh24miss'))
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a separate format for timestamps.  It is `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`. You set this just as you would the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` for the session.